How to define spread operator type - TypeScript
I have an interface which defines the function signature of various functions
interface AndroidInterface {
  getXo: () => string | null;
  getOx: () => string | null;
  saveXo: (xo: string) => void;
  saveOx: (ox: string) => void;
  getGaid: () => string | null;
  sendAnalyticsEvents: (
    eventName: string,
    eventProperties: Record<string, unknown>
  ) => void;
  getAppVersionCode: () => number | null;
  getClientId: () => string | null;
  getConfig: () => Record<string, unknown> | null;
  isFirstAppLogin: () => boolean;
  logout: () => void;
  openWhatsapp: (message: string, phone: string) => void;
}

These are basically methods on the androidInterfaceMethods object on window exposed through JS bridge. Meaning:
interface Window{
 androidInterfaceMethods?: AndroidInterface;
}

Now, I have a function that dynamically invokes the methods on the androidInterfaceMethods object. The function is defined and typed as follows:
const invokeAndroidInterface = <K extends keyof AndroidInterface>(
  methodName: K,
  ...args: Parameters<AndroidInterface[K]>
): ReturnType<AndroidInterface[K]> | null => {
 
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.androidInterfaceMethods) {
    const method = window.androidInterfaceMethods[methodName];
    if (typeof method === "function") {
        return method(...args);
    }
  }
  return null
}

But strangely, I'm getting a red squiggly underline on method(...args) with the message:

A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

I'd ideally not want to assert window.androidInterfaceMethods[methodName]; and would instead want TS to infer the function signature correctly. I tried using type guards, but that didn't help either.
As an experiment, when I hover over the method variable, the type is AndroidInterface[K] which is as expected. Further to verify, I hardcoded the method name, e,g:
const method = window.androidInterfaceMethods["sendAnalyticsEvents"]; and now the type of the method variable showed (eventName: string, eventProperties: Record<string, unknown>) => void;, but that didn't solve the issue, but finally when I asserted ...args as AndroidInterface["sendAnalyticsEvents"] it worked as expected.
Alternatively, asserting window.androidInterfaceMethods[methodName] as Function also fixes the issue, but I believe it is not entirely correct.
Could anyone please shed some light here?

Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without typos or unrelated errors. Valmo⋯ and return null each have errors you're not asking about.

(see prev comment) Once you fix those, the issue here is that TS can't see the higher-order relationship you care about; it's essentially ms/TS#30581 and the recommended fix is to make the relationship explicit in the types, as described at ms/TS#47109, and as shown in this playground link. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a suitable duplicate; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz pardon me for the typo, it was supposed to be  AndroidInterface, I've updated it. Regarding return null, it didn't seem like a critical issue that I needed help with.

Yes, the solution in the playground fully addresses the question. Thanks a lot. A detailed answer would be appreciated.

If you don't need help with it then it's, at best, a distraction. You can either annotate to return | null or throw an error instead of return null. Which one do you want to see for the purposes of this question?

I was looking for the former approach (| null).
